What does "predicted" mean in an electronic configuration?
I've noticed the term "(predicted)" appearing at the end of electron configurations for heavier elements. Could you explain what it signifies and the reason behind it? I haven't been able to find any explanations online.


I think it's clear what a prediction is? What does "something" mean? is wording bad enough to downvote by itself - you have to say why you don't get something, not just just state it.

It’s not stable sufficiently long to get empirical data (or even get the right number of electrons), so prediction is all we got.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163553/how-many-elements-have-been-identified-for-which-there-are-no-known-spectral-lin is relevant.

Think about how one would measure a value for that element (and others as unstable), rather than predict a value based on calculation or extrapolation.

The "predicted" notation signifies that the electron configurations for heavier elements are forecasts. While the Aufbau Principle accurately predicts configurations for lighter elements,  relativistic effects become crucial when looking at heavier atoms.  These effects, arising from electrons traveling at speeds closer to the speed of light, alter energy levels and complicate calculations. Furthermore, these predictions rely on advanced computational models like Hartree-Fock theory(just an example!), where the motion of each electron can be expressed as a single-particle function (orbital), independent of the other electrons' instantaneous motions. The "predicted" tag acknowledges the theoretical nature of these configurations and the limitations of the Aufbau principle for heavier elements.
Consequently, scientists rely on advanced computational models such as relativistic functional density theory as well, with quantum electrodynamical corrections, to predict electron configurations in superheavy elements. Try checking this out as well (if you are interested in seeing computational methods of prediction), where they predict the electron config for elements 121 to 131 (yes, they are hypothetical): https://journals.jps.jp/doi/pdf/10.1143/JPSJ.65.3175

"Predicted" in the context of electronic configuration has the same meaning as in all nature and social sciences.
It means the behaviour or state that is expected by a related theoretical model to be or to happen.
The other way is to experimentally observe such a state or behaviour.
There are created just few nuclei of such heavy elements  and there is usually no chance to observe most of atomic or element properties and behaviours. So many can be just predicted.
